# How do I get a JavaScript global variable and send it into a php file?

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, phaser-framework

I am building a game using phaser game development and I want to send the score into mySQL database but JS and PHP don't directly communicate. I am using AJAX but I'm stuck. Here is my code:

```
<!doctype html> 
<html lang="en"> 
<head> 
<meta charset="UTF-8" />
<title>Star Runner</title>
<script>window.score=0;</script>
<script src="phaser.js"></script>

</head>
<body>

<script type="text/javascript">

// game goes here

</script>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $.ajax({
            url: "inscore.php",
            type: 'POST',
            data: 'score='+score,
            cache: false,
            success: function(data) {
                    alert(data);}
        });

    });



</script>

<h1 style="color:white">Star Runner</h1

</body>
</html>
```

My php file 'inscore.php' would be:

```
<?php

include 'login.php';
$score = $_GET['score'];

echo "<p>". $score. "</p>"; 
//SQL queries

?>
```

I'm not sure if I should link this page to the php page because I just want the score to update into my database immediately after the game is done. Can someone please help me?

Comment: Move you js code into another <script> tag. Your code won't work.

Comment: Make sure your jquery include is above your js code. For failure safe.

Answer (score 1):

First, there is a little mistake in your code.

Your Code:

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js">
  // code here will not run
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $.ajax({
      // ...
    });
  });
</script>
```

It suppose to be:

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $.ajax({
      // ...
    });
  });
</script>
```

And here is a example for you:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Star Runner</title>
  <script src="phaser.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <h1 style="color:white">Star Runner</h1>
  <div>
    Game stage ...
  </div>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script>
    // game goes here
    var Game = {
      score: 0,
      run: function() {
        // your awesome code
        if (true) {
          this.gameOver();
        }
      },
      gameOver: function() {
        var _this = this;
        // send the request
        $.ajax({
          url: "inscore.php",
          type: 'POST',
          data: 'score=' + this.score,
          cache: false,
          success: function(data) {
            // balabala
            console.log(_this);
          }
        });
      }
    };
    // Run the game
    Game.run();
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

It is better to use OOP (Object Oriented Programming), especially in the game project.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are posting data on your ajax, you should get the data on PHP's $_POST global variable

```
<?php

include 'login.php';
$score = $_POST['score'];

echo "<p>". $score. "</p>"; 
//SQL queries

?>
```

And try to use a php framework like laravel or symfony for this project, even a simplier one like slim would be better for you to get things done